# i can't install caffe on anaconda CPU-only windows 10

Tags: python, cmake, deep-learning, anaconda, caffe

I'm getting this error while install caffe !:

...........................................................................

```
    The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 1
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Ninja"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 1
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 2
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 1
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 0
INFO: ============================================================
The system cannot find the path specified.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Projects/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

ERROR: Configure failed
```

............................................................................

system info: i'm using windows 10 64-bit OS

installed :
anaconda
python 2.7 and python 3.6
i don't have GPU so just CPU-only

if any one can help me with this i'll appreciate that >

Comment: Have you tried to google for error message `No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found`? There are pretty numbers of posts about such error.

Comment: what command did you use for installation...i guess you are building...not that depending ?

Comment: yes  I tried to install caffe using this link : https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to set to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`.  This can be done by editing `scripts/build_win.cmd` to provide the correct path to your C and C++ compilers when running cmake (roughly around line 160)

Eg.

```
cmake -G"!CMAKE_GENERATOR!" ^
...
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe" ^
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe" ^
...
```